# Want to 301 redirect www.domain.com to ww.domain.com

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns

Hello it s been 3 days that Im trying to redirect www.domain.com to ww.domain.com I ve added A (ww) and Ip of server on dns when I try ww.domain.com it s 403 error help please !

Comment: Do you have an issue with setting up the 301 response? Or is your issue with ww.domain.com being forbidden(403)?

Comment: ww.domain.com forbidden

Comment: 403 response is coming from (hopefully yours) webserver, so we need to see the webserver configuration in order to troubleshoot it.